# How to create a protocol extension that returns the confirming type?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

I am trying to implement a protocol extension JsonProcess which has a function that takes NSData as the argument and i want to create different protocol extensions using self requirement something like this

```
extension JSONResource where Self: Login {
    func proccessJSON(data: NSData) -> Self{
        return Login()
    }
}
```

but the compiler shows an error

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Login' to return type 'Self'

the Login class is defined like this

```
class Login: NSObject {
    var username: String?
    var firstName: String?
}
```

what should I return here if i serialize the NSData and create an isntanse of the Login class populate it  and try to return it?

Comment: func proccessJSON(data: NSData) -> Login?

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified that the extension only applies if conforming object `Self` is class `Login` you should write extension like this:

```
extension JSONResource where Self: Login {
    func proccessJSON(data: NSData) -> Login {
        return Login()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `Self` is potentially more type-specific than `Login`. Let's say you create a subclass of `Login`:

```
class TopSecretLogin : Login {
    var topSecret : String?
}
```

Now when you come to use your protocol extension on an instance of `TopSecretLogin` (assuming `Login` conforms to `JSONResource` in the first place) – your `processJSON` method says that it returns `Self`, which is `TopSecretLogin` in this case. However, you're trying to return a `Login`. Therefore the compiler isn't happy, as you cannot pass a superclass to something that expects its subclass.

The solution depends on whether you intend for `Login` to be subclassed. If you don't intend for it to be subclassed, then simply change the method signature to returning a `Login`, and make `Login` a `final class`.

If you do intend for this, you need to add a required initialiser to `Login`, allowing you to construct an arbitrary instance of `Self` in your protocol extension. An example setup could look like this:

```
protocol JSONResource {}

class Login : NSObject, JSONResource {

    var username: String?
    var firstName: String?

    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

class TopSecretLogin : Login {

    var topSecret : String?

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

extension JSONResource where Self : Login {
    func processJSON(data: NSData) -> Self {

        // do some processing...

        return Self()
    }
}

let someData = // ...

let l = Login()
l.processJSON(someData) // returns Login

let t = TopSecretLogin()
t.processJSON(someData) // returns TopSecretLogin
```

---

Although that all being said, wouldn't it make more sense if `processJSON` was a static method instead of an instance method? To me it doesn't look like it needs to operate on an instance, it just creates a new instance from a given set of `NSData`.

You also may want to consider making `processJSON` a protocol requirement, as surely anything that's a `JSONResource` should be able to `processJSON`? In that case you'll want to extend `Login` rather than the protocol itself in order to implement the method. You can then create a new instance through `self.init()` at the static scope, or `self.dynamicType.init()` at instance scope.

You may also want to consider doing this with an initialiser:

```
protocol JSONResource {
    init(jsonData:NSData)
}

class Login : NSObject, JSONResource {

    var username: String?
    var firstName: String?

    required init(jsonData:NSData) {

        // do some processing

        super.init()
    }
}

class TopSecretLogin : Login {

    var topSecret : String?

    required init(jsonData:NSData) {

        // do some processing

        super.init(jsonData:jsonData)
    }
}

let someData = // ...

let l = Login(jsonData: someData) // returns Login

let t = TopSecretLogin(jsonData: someData) // returns TopSecretLogin
```